# MVC 5 - Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported - System.Runtime.dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, compiler-errors, assembly-binding-redirect

I am not sure what happened but my website on my localhost (IIS, Visual Studio 2017 v 15.2 rel 26430.16, Framework 4.7.02046) started throwing this compile error when starting up any webpage:

> error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been
>   imported: ... System.Runtime.dll

The callstack starts:

> System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): (0): error CS1703:
>   Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported:
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll'
>   and 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8eef972c\49b00562\assembly\dl3\4fee60ec\2db40549_62dbd001\System.Runtime.dll'.
>   Remove one of the duplicate references. --->
>   System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005): (0): error CS1703:
>   Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported:
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll'
>   and 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8eef972c\49b00562\assembly\dl3\4fee60ec\2db40549_62dbd001\System.Runtime.dll'.
>   Remove one of the duplicate references. at
>   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()

Looking at the System.Runtime.dll files in both locations shows

- **4.7.2046.0** (3/18/2017) C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a
- **2.6.10.0** (8/20/2015) C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8eef972c\49b00562\assembly\dl3\4fee60ec\2db40549_62dbd001

Web.config had this binding redirect:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.10.0" newVersion="2.6.10.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Commenting out that section solved the problem.

This must be something particular about my development environment. Other developers do not have the issue (nor the build server or production).

Can explain what is going on? Is there a different recommended solution?

I think I did enable some Framework 4.7 options but I am not sure. This is not AspNet Core - it's MVC5 targeting Framework 4.6.1 with the NuGet Microsoft Compiler packages to support C#7.